# In r, does the order of the class vector matter in class inheritance

Tags: r, inheritance

```
x <- c(1, 10, 100)
y <- list(1, 2, 3)
z <- list(5, 50, 500)

a <- tibble(x, y, z)
```

Is this:

```
class(a) <- c("my_new_class", class(a))
```

different from this:

```
class(a) <- c(class(a), "my_new_class")
```

Obviously, "my_new_class" inherits from tibble. So which order conveys that?

Answer (score 2):

The order of the classes is important for generic function since the order determines the search order of the generic function that might be applied. The explanation found for the `class()` function explains it nicely:

> When a generic function fun is applied to an object with class attribute c("first", "second"), the system searches for a function called fun.first and, if it finds it, applies it to the object. If no such function is found, a function called fun.second is tried. If no class name produces a suitable function, the function fun.default is used (if it exists). If there is no class attribute, the implicit class is tried, then the default method.

In your case the first part of the code

```
x <- c(1, 10, 100)
y <- list(1, 2, 3)
z <- list(5, 50, 500)

a <- tibble(x, y, z)
class(a) <- c("my_new_class", class(a))
```

produces an object `a` with these classes

```
class(a)
[1] "my_new_class" "tbl_df"       "tbl"          "data.frame"
```

The second produces

```
class(a) <- c(class(a), "my_new_class")
class(a)
[1] "tbl_df"       "tbl"          "data.frame"   "my_new_class"
```

The order is clearly different but perhaps the best example is already given by using a tibble as a replacement for the standard `data.frames`. When you create a tibble the order of the classes is `"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"`. Thus, functions that are *not* created for tibbles but for data frames will still work as the function searches through the classes and triggers a hit for the last `data.table`.

Had the order been reversed, `"data.frame", "tbl", "tbl_df"` then any function that would accept a standard `data.frame` would trigger first.

Hope this explains the importance of the different orders.